# Background-image property isnt working outside of vs code liveserver

Tags: html, css

My first question here. Apologies if my format/grammar is wrong. Also, I'm just learning web dev.

So I have a .css file that contains this:

```
.bgimg-1 {
  background-image: url('/img/back2.jpg');
  min-height: 100%;
}

.bgimg-2 {
  background-image: url('/img/back3.jpg');
  min-height: 400px;
}

.bgimg-3 {
  background-image: url('/img/back4.jpg');
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

My problem is the Html file displays images properly in the live server but not if I directly double-click the index.html.
Now hear me out I tried doing this **'../img/back3.jpg'** instead as it was suggested in another answer to the same problem but for me, it won't fix it. The images still won't show. Now the crazy thing is, if I open the broken image links in new tab the path in the address bar shows **'C:/Users/Username/Desktop/img/back3.jpg'** in the case of **'../'** and if I remove the **'../'** it shows **'C:/img/back3.jpg'** 
idk whats going on. Please help me.

to clarify this is the path of the img folder on my system.
**C:/Users/Username/Desktop/Project/img**

this is the path it shows if I use **'../img/back3.jpg'**.
**'C:/Users/Username/Desktop/img/back3.jpg'**

this is the path it shows if I use **'/img/back3.jpg'**.
**'C:/img/back3.jpg'**

Again: In live server, any of the above approaches work.

Comment: have you tried  './img' ?

Comment: can you add your html path too?

Comment: Okay, I tried './img' as MaxK suggested. I have a <img> that displays the image properly using './' in the src. Thanks, that solves part of my problem  :). But doing that for the CSS changes nothing. The elements where these classes are applied still don't show background.

RezaHashemi here is my html path:  C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Project\index.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay so, @MaxK's suggestion led me to an answer. I still don't know what './' and '../' does, but I will be looking into it. That being said, I fixed my problem by changing the CSS path to **'.\css\base.css'** i.e. added a '.' That fixed some of the other visual elements which I am shocked that I didn't notice as missing before.

The bgimages still won't show though so I tried adding '..\img\' as the URL. And that somehow fixed it. Have not changed the folder structure at all. Can't understand how '.' works in someplace and '..' in some other.

To clarify: added a '.' in the path of the CSS file where one links the stylesheet in the header.

added a '..' to the bgimg class image URLs. That fixed it.